# Correct way of initialize COM C++ service multithread

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-services

Has any effect use of COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE with COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag in CoInitializeEx call:

```
CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quote [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> In addition to the flags already mentioned, it is a good idea to set
>   the COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE flag in the dwCoInit parameter. Setting
>   this flag avoids some overhead associated with Object Linking and
>   Embedding (OLE) 1.0, an obsolete technology.

Comment: But in this example there are only references using the flag COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.

Comment: The threading model doesn't matter. The flag performs the same function in either case.